# IntelliJ run all threads stopped at a breakpoint

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a breakpoint in my code that I made [to suspend all threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGW8v.png) but in order to test a bug I want to run all the stopped threads at the breakpoint at the same time but I can't figure it out. I can only resume the threads 1-by-1 and that is too slow for my test any help?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run all the stopped threads at the breakpoint at the same time but I can't figure it out.

I know of no way to do this. Sounds like you are relying on specific timing of the threads  to find your bug which is going to be very hard to reproduce in the debugger. A debugger is also likely to muck with the memory synchronization of the program meaning that it will most likely not run the same way as outside of the debugger.

I think you need to start thinking about other ways to locate your bug.  Debugging with `System.out.println(...)` messages has it's own problems because it synchronizes memory as well but writing to `FileOutputStream` or other non synchronized logging might be one mechanism that will give you information about what the threads are doing without having too much impact on the interaction between threads.

Debugging threaded programs is really hard.  I'm working on a [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) right now actually so I can relate.  Best of luck!